# What monsters does Windproof (Lo) and Earplugs NOT work on?

Tags: monster-hunter-4-ultimate

The description for Windproof (Lo) reads: "Lessens almost all Wind Pressure."

And the description for Windproof (Hi) reads: "Negates Wind Pressure from almost all monsters."

Well, that's just maddeningly unhelpful. For which monsters do I need Windproof (Hi) for? I assume Kushala Daora is probably one, but some sources say that even Windproof (Hi) doesn't work on him.

While we're on the topic of resistance skills, how about Earplugs? I play Insect Glaive so I know normal Earplugs don't work on Tigrex, Akantor, and some others, but I'm not exactly sure of the comprehensive list.

Answer (score 1):

Windproof (Lo): Protects from the little wind "puff" that some monster generate when they start flying or landing, this is mostly true for the smaller monsters (Yan Kut-Ku, Rathian,Diablos burrowing...), When Figthing bigger and stronger monsters the windpresure they generate is bigger and for that you need the next level.

Windproof (Hi): the special dragon trio from monster hunter 3 can ignore this skill.

The trio are:

- Kushala daora
- Chameleos
- Teostra

This is because they not only have a strong wind presure, but a special ability, in case of teostra and kushala is an elemental wind wall, in the case of chameleos it's a mix of tremor and wind push.

Earplugs: this skill has 2 level like windproof (Lo) and (Hi), (Lo) gives protection to many monster and (Hi) makes you immune to all roars.

Tigrex,Ankantor, Ukanlos and all their variants have a special roar that has the special ability to damage the hunter if he is too close, Earplugs don't work because you are hit by the sound blast damage and pushing you away, if you are just outside the damaging area you won't be affected by the sound like all other roars

The list of monster that require Earplugs (Hi) is:

- Zamtrios
- Najarala
- Khezu
- Basarios
- Gravios
- Gore Magala
- Shagaru Magala
- Monoblos
- Diablos
- Deviljho
- Silver Rathalos
- Gold Rathian
- Dahren Mohran
- Dalamadur
- Fatalis
- Gogmazios

Comment: would be nice to know why the negative vote

Comment: probably lack of source?

Comment: This answer just doesn't seem to address the question at all. "(Lo) gives protection to many monster" is not any better than the ingame description, and it doesn't address Windproof at all.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer the list would be too big but i can probably add a list of all the monster that require (Hi) Earplugs. everything else would require only low

Comment: "Tigrex,Ankantor, some Elder Dragons". Still incredibly vague, still doesn't address Windproof.